# France communes shapefiles

Tags: data-request, geospatial, france

Where can I find a free dataset of all the shapefiles of boundaries of France "communes" administrative divisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best source I could point you to - [Découpage administratif communal français issu d'OpenStreetMap](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/decoupage-administratif-communal-francais-issu-d-openstreetmap/)

Comment: For non french speaking users, go down in the page to the section "Ressources" there are download links.